# How to find path to specific ros package in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Is it possible to get path to specific ros package in CMakeLists.txt ?
If yes, how can I do it ?

There could be multiple directories with the same name like [navigation](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation).
(navigation metapackage directory is in navigation directory)
I'd like to find a path to navigation metapackage directory in this case.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223748/how-to-find-path-to-specific-ros-package-in-cmakelists.txt/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2016-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using `catkin`,  what you should as `rosbuild` will be eventually removed sometime, all ros packages can easily be found using `find_package(catkin REQUIRED <PKG>)`, but you need to add the dependency to the `package.xml` as well.

There cannot be multiple packages with the same name on your path, or, more precisly, in one of the directories in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. in each "level", (i.e. workspace, /opt/ros, ...) you can only have one.

The names of directories have nothing to do with the package names. The exception is the directory name of the package itself, i.e. which contains the `package.xml` and the `CMakeLists.txt`. This is the name of your package and is also listed in the `package.xml`.

By convention, most repositories have the name of the meta-package they contain. But this does not need to be like that!
So in your case, only having a dependency to `navigation` is fine.

**HOWEVER** you should never depend on a meta-package, but only on regular packages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0